# PHP: json_decode stops further code from executing

Tags: php, json, http-headers, soundcloud

this is my code:

```
echo "START";
echo "<br />";

try {
    $check = json_decode($soundcloud->get('me/followings/2521254'), true);
} catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
} 

echo "<br />";
echo "END";
```

When I execute the file it looks like this:

```
START
The requested URL responded with HTTP code 303.
```

The HTTP code 303 does mean that the user is following a specific person (if not it's 404), but that's not the point - this question is not SoundCloud API related.

**The actual problem is:** the echo (`echo "END";`) after the try block isn't executing.

What's the problem, how can I solve this?

Comment: Because you are calling the exit() function, if an exception is thrown.

Comment: Oh thats very embarrassing, I'm sorry. I was totally focusing on the try area and absolutely forgot the catch area. Thank you very much.